# Etherscan event retrieval. Topic

Tags: events, etherscan

Here's the [contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8C4D48B42cdff260F14BBaD4E10d4144F1898bD4#events) events I want to pull from the ropsten network.

Here's how I constructed the event request

```
event_request =  ("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs"+
                 f"&fromBlock={from_block}"+
                 f"&toBlock={to_block}" +
                 f"&address{contract_address}"+
                 "&topic0=0xf63780e752c6a54a94fc52715dbc5518a3b4c3c2833d301a204226548a2a8545" +
                 f"&apikey={api}")
result = json.loads(http.request(event_request)[1].decode("utf-8"))
```

Which gives me valid results, but I don't see any of the transaction in the specified link. I think I'm spposed to change the topic0 value but not sure what to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this (using web3.js v1.x):

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
console.log(Web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)"));
```

Gives this:

```
0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
```

Comment: So are you saying that's the value topic0 should be assigned to?

Comment: @financial_physician: I wrote that very explicitly as far as I can tell.